# Can this circle chart be made with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'd like to make a data visualisation with d3.js.
I'm wondering if it's possible to make such one? : [image: Graph]

The data looks like this: A (actual number): 25%, B (target number): 32%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! you can make using the d3 pie layout something like this:

I am assuming that you have a data set like how you have explained in the question:

```
data = [{
    "label": "Actual",
        "percent": 25
}, {
    "label": "Target",
        "percent": 75
}]
```

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["orange", "gray"]);

var actualarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 10);

var targetarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var labelarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius + 70)
    .innerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.percent;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



data = [{
    "label": "Actual",
        "percent": 25
}, {
    "label": "Target",
        "percent": 75
}]

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    console.log(d)
    if (d.data.label == "Actual") {
        console.log("actual")
        return actualarc(d);

    } else {
        console.log("target")
        return targetarc(d);
    }
})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
});

g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + labelarc.centroid(d) + ")";
})
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
})
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.data.percent + "%";
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
}
text {
    font-size:40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your example is missing the target marker, isn't it?

Comment: yea skipped it ... don't know if it was needed its an extra effort after all :)

Comment: I just wanted to make this clear. Looking at the quality of the question I wouldn't put to much effort into it. At least you paved the way.

Comment: Hi Cyril, Thank you a lot! looks really great, I'm sorry for the unclear question, but what I would like to do is to overlap two donut charts.

Comment: Sorry if the question looked insincere I just wanted to keep it short.. I wouldn't ask for the code, but could you kindly let me know if it's possible at all to make a mark like that (with another data) on the top of the chart you made?

Comment: OK MOOZI i didnt explain that in the answer...you dont need to make 2 donut charts... but you should be making 2 arcs check the _targetarc_ and _actualarc_. For placing the labels correctly in the centroid i used another arc _labelarc_

Comment: ... yes you can make a mark or make line like shown in the image by connecting the centroids of the arc _labelarc_ and _targetarc_

Comment: Many thanks Cyril, that's great :) Actually I'm not a developer but really wanted to use the visualisation for a project. I'm so glad that it's possible with d3! Thanks again!